# Query issue with parent-children relation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following children-father mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "my_parent": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type": "string"  },
            "body" : { "type": "string"  },
            "source_id" : { "type": "integer"  },
        }
    },
    "my_child": {
      "_parent": {"type": "my_parent" },
      "properties" : {
            "user_id" : { "type": "string"  },
}}}}'
```

... this two parents with ids `10` and `11`:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_parent/10' -d '{
  "title" : "Microsiervos - Discos duros de 10TB",
  "body" : "Empiezan a sacar DD de 30GB en el mercado",
  "source_id" : "27",
}'

curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_parent/11' -d '{
  "title" : "Microsiervos - En el 69 llegamos a la luna",
  "body" : "Se cumplen 3123 anos de la llegada a la luna",
  "source_id" : "27",
}'
```

... and this two childrens:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_child/1234_10?parent=10' -d '{
  "user_id": "1234",
}'

curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_child/1234_11?parent=11' -d '{
  "user_id": "1234",
}'
```

With the following query, I want to get the `_id` of the father with `user_id = 1234`.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_parent/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "_source" : "_id",
  "query": {
    "has_child": { 
      "type": "my_child",
      "query" : {
           "query_string" : {
               "default_field" : "user_id",
               "query" : "1234"
}}}}}'
```

This outputs the two `ids`, `10` and `11`.

Now I want to search on parent on those specific `ids` only, something like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_parent/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "_id": ["10", "11"]
         }},
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "body",
            "query": "mercado"
}}]}}}'
```

As you can notice, the `"_id": ["10", "11"]` part is written by hand. I would like to know if there's a way to combine this two queries in one single query putting the `ids` returned in the first query automatically on the second query.

So the output to this should be:

```
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.69177496,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "my_parent",
      "_id" : "10",
      "_score" : 0.69177496,
      "_source":{
  "title" : "Microsiervos - Discos duros de 10TB",
  "body" : "Empiezan a sacar DD de 30GB en el mercado",
  "source_id" : "27"
}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bool Query` and put both conditions in `must`:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_parent/_search" -d'
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
              "default_field": "body",
              "query": "mercado"
           }
        },
        {
           "has_child": {
              "type": "my_child",
              "query": {
                 "query_string": {
                    "default_field": "user_id",
                    "query": "1234"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
     }
  }
}'
```